# How to mention the Channel and Event name in flutter websockets

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, dart, websocket

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.0.164:6001/app/KEY'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.channel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: widget.channel.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {

            if(snapshot.hasError)
               print(snapshot.error);
            else {
              widget.channel.sink.add("123");
              print("XXX : ${snapshot.data}");
            }

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
              child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The output of the Print Statement is

**XXX : {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{"socket_id":"943971557.707744157","activity_timeout":30}"}**

It does not fetch refreshed data as the Event and Channel isn't mentioned for my laravel backend. Is there a way that can be mentioned or have i got it wrong somewhere else?

Comment: did you found a solution for it ?